# Can the right operand of an overloaded binary operator be an object of a fundamental type?

Tags: c++, object, types, operator-overloading

Does this work or do both the operands need to be objects of user-defined types?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

At least one of the operands for an overloaded binary operator needs to be user-defined. But they don't both have to be.

For instance, a pair of legal but useless definitions:

```
enum class foo { bar };

void operator+(int, foo) {}
void operator*(foo, int) {}
```

The above makes `1 + foo::bar` and `foo::bar*2` valid expressions (that do nothing).